# RequireJS load only concatenated file

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, r.js

I'm using RequireJS (version 2.1.14) and would like to concatenate my JavaScript files into one single `app-built.js`.
I've created a little node module which reads my `app.js`, extracts the project paths and gets executed once I run `node build` in the `js` directory of my application.

The node module (build.js):

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    directory = __dirname + path.sep,
    requirejs = require(directory + 'vendor/r.js');

fs.readFile(directory + 'app.js', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return
    } else {
        data = data.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/\s+/g, '');
        var paths = data.substr(data.indexOf('{'), data.indexOf('}')),
            paths = paths.substr(0, paths.indexOf('}') + 1),
            paths = JSON.parse(paths);

        createAppBuilt(paths);
    }
});

function createAppBuilt(paths) {
    var config = {
        baseUrl: __dirname,
        paths: paths,
        name: 'app',
        out: 'app-built.js',
        preserveLicenseComments: false,
        findNestedDependencies: true,
        removeCombined: true
    };

    requirejs.optimize(config, function(buildResponse) {
        var contents = fs.readFileSync(config.out, 'utf8');
        console.log('Created app-built.js');
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
    });
}
```

app.js:

```
var paths = {
    'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min',
    // other paths
};

// Set language, necessary for validtaion plugin -> validation.js
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    localStorage.getItem('language') || localStorage.setItem('language', navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
}

requirejs.config({
    paths: paths,
    shim: {
        touchswipe: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        icheck: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        validate: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        mask: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        chosenImage: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'chosen']
        },
        cookie: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require(['globals', 'jquery', 'underscore'], function() {

    var initial = ['main'];

    if (!Modernizr.localstorage) {
        initial.push('cookie');
    }

    require(initial, function(Main) {
        $(function() {
            if (!Modernizr.localstorage) {
                $.cookie.json = true;
            }
            Main.init();
        });
    });

});
```

The `app-built.js` gets generated but when I include it in my index.php all the other modules get loaded as well. How can I prevent the loading of all modules and only load the `app-built.js`?

[image]

Comment: Does your ``app-built.js`` file contains the modules you expect? Please add to your question the all the original HTML statements that have to do with loading and configuring RequireJS and your application. (Your image show what some scripts tags *after* RequireJS has started. This is useful but what I'm looking for is what RequireJS initially sees when it starts.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the r.js optimizer (to uglify2) solved the problem for me:

```
var config = {
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    paths: paths,
    name: 'app',
    out: 'app-built.js',
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    removeCombined: true,
    optimize: 'uglify2'
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you look into http://webpack.github.io/
or http://browserify.org/ as these solve this problem for you.

They allow you to use `require` much as before, yet the code is compiled/concatenated into a single file.

Webpack allows for a bit more flexibility in loading different chunks of code for different parts of your site, but Browserify is the most well-known so far.

There may be a cost in switching over to these, as I don't think that they're 100% compatible requirejs, however they bring great advantages.

[Here's](http://esa-matti.suuronen.org/blog/2013/03/22/journey-from-requirejs-to-browserify/) someone's journey from RequireJS to Browserify with some Pros and Cons.

Answer (score -1):

Separate modules into different files, e.g. `app-built.js`, `user-built.js`. Then load script when it's needed.

Here's a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/s6hUOEHjRbDhtGxaagdR?p=preview .

When page loaded, requirejs only loads `global.js`. After clicking the `Change Color` button, requirejs starts to load `colorfy.js` and `random-color.js`, which required by `colorfy.js`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the exact details, but, yet if you don't have an `exports` option, r.js doesn't define a named module for you, that causes to actually load the script.

I assume you have jquery plugins there so add this extra `exports` option:

```
shim: {
    touchswipe: {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: 'jQuery.fn.touchswipe'
    },
```

This should force r.js to build a named module for touchswipe:

```
define("touchswipe", (function (global) {
    return function () {
        var ret, fn;
        return ret || global.jQuery.fn.touchswipe;
    };
}(this)));
```

Note that, `exports` option might not build this named module, in that case your best bet is to include this manually.

Again I am not sure about why and how this happens, It must be a bug in requirejs, it's unlikely there is a tweak for this.